# Cannot boot to windows after deleting Linux Partition(s). Stuck with grub rescue

Tags: linux, filesystems, windows, grub, rescue

I just updated my PC to Windows 10, and deleted my Linux partitions. After a restart, it came up with grub rescue. I've tried booting from a Windows recovery disk and doing

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
```

PS: Doing `ls (hd0.msdosX)` all return Unknown Filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Install windows first. Add linux as one of the startup options.

Option 2: Install windows first, when you install the linux on a different partition, set grub to "boot from partition" instead of mbr.